# Tracing a multiplication table w/ Python trace()

Tags: python, trace, multiplication, execution

I'm interested in finding out how to implement Python's trace module to follow the execution of a multiplication table and print its annotated results.

I researched Python documentation and internet sources related to trace() and the multiplication program, but I came up empty-handed.

```
import sys
import trace

tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)

def print_multiples(n, high):
    for i in range(1, high+1):
        print(n * i, end="   ")
    print()

def print_mult_table(high):
    """ Return a multiplication table with n rows and columns."""
    for i in range(1, high+1):
        print_multiples(i, high)

print_mult_table(7)

r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

Again, I'd like to figure out how to implement Python's trace module to follow the execution of a multiplication table and print it annotated results.